# How to use Microsoft SQL Server without SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2016

I am trying to use SQL Server 2016, both SQL Server & Management Studio  installation completed succesfully. When opening SQL Server Management Studio, I get this error:

> One or more componenet missing, please reinstall the program

I have almost tried all the possible solutions found on the internet, but at the end I keep getting the same error. Now I am tryig to replace SQL Server Management Studio, please some suggest to what software I could use to run SQL Server properly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: SSMS isn't broken. If it was, thousands of developers would be up in arms. They aren't. If your installation is broken, fix it. How did you install it, what were those `all the possible solution found in the internet` ? What is the *exact* error message?

Comment: SSMS is a [separately downloadable product](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms). It's current version is 17.3. What did you install? Which version?

Comment: hi! thanks for quick replay. I will post another question in detail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193783/error-opening-sql-server-management-studio-17-3

Answer (score 1):

Check The Following

[5 Free Alternatives to Microsoft SQL Management Studio](https://www.vladan.fr/5-free-alternatives-microsoft-sql-management-studio/).

I Think [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is good

Comment: If your car's mirror is crooked, do you ditch the car or fix the mirror?

Comment: And Linqpad has nothing to do with managing SQL Server instances. It's only used for querying

Comment: @AtikurRahaman there's nothing wrong with SSMS. Install the latest version and post the *actual error message*.

Comment: @well said  Panagiotis Kanavos :)

Comment: I am posting another question with details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47193783/error-opening-sql-server-management-studio-17-3