# Error opening SQL Server Management Studio 17.3

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms, ssms-2016

I recently installed SQL Server 2016, amd as we know SQL Server and SQL Server Management Studio now are separate downloads, so I download SQL Server Management Studio 17.3 and installed it on my PC.

After installing, when opening it for first time, it worked perfectly, but after rebooting or reopening SSMS 17, I get this following error:

[image]

Please help me to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Have you uninstalled and reinstalled it again?

Comment: yes, several time, double check required software even changed my os. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Management Studio 17 cannot find one or more components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43807502/sql-server-management-studio-17-cannot-find-one-or-more-components)

Comment: How can i fix the error, most importantly after changing my os, I installed sql server 2016 than SSMS 17.3 one after another, I think this time duplicate install can't be possible but faced same error.

Comment: Did you read the question and top voted answer from the duplicate question linked?